# How to make a request for a external json data?

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't just import things like HttpClient or HttpResponse to manage requests because they are don't exists for my project. No import possibility.

In my gradle.build I have:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
}
```

My sdk versions:

```
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 23
```

My question is: which way is possible to retrieve just a simple json data from a external storage in my case?
Or should I check some configuration files to get typical things working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to use External Storage, you can use [raw](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.raw.html) resources.

Putting file "json" in `src/main/res/raw` can be retrieved using the following

```
String getJson(Context context) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    InputStream ios = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.json);
    int ctr;
    try {
        ctr = ios.read();
        while (ctr != -1) {
            baos.write(ctr);
            ctr = ios.read();
        }
        ios.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (baos != null) {
        return baos.toString();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

From there you can parse the string and get your data.

Comment: But by "external storage" I meant a data that is available through api of web page (or portal) where from I going to retrieve data. Thank you for your reply, but are you available to give some edits that I can use for getting JSON from some provided urls, please?